# Replace a substring of file name

Tags: python, replace, substring, rename

Sorry if this question has been already asked before. I didn't find an answer by searching.
In need to replace a sub string of a file name in Python.

**Old String**: "_ready"

**New String**: "_busy"

**Files**: a_ready.txt, b_ready.txt, c.txt, d_blala.txt, e_ready.txt

**Output**:a_busy.txt, b_busy.txt, c.txt, d_blala.txt, e_busy.txt

Any ideas? I tried to use replce(), but nothing happen. The files are still with the old names.

Here is my code:

```
import os

counter = 0

for file in os.listdir("c:\\test"):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        if file.find("_ready") > 0:
            counter = counter + 1
            print ("old name:" + file)
            file.replace("_ready", "_busy")
            print ("new name:" + file)
if counter == 0:
    print("No file has been found")
```

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want to change file names in a list or do you want to rename the actual files?

Comment: Well, both will be good for me. When i'll know how to change actual file name, i'll be able to change a list of a files. Anyway, the final propose will be a list of a files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The other answer have shown you that you can replace a substring with `string.replace`. What you need is [`os.rename`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename).

```
import os
counter = 0
path = "c:\\test"
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        if file.find("_ready") > -1:
            counter = counter + 1
            os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, file.replace("_ready", "_busy")))
if counter == 0:
    print("No file has been found")
```

The problem with your code is that strings in python are immutable, so `replace` returns a new string which you have to replace the current `file` and add to a list if you want to use it later:

```
files = [] # list of tuple with old filename and new filename
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        if file.find("_ready") > -1:
            counter = counter + 1
            newFileName = file.replace("_ready", "_busy"))
            files.append((file, newFileName))
```

Comment: Instead of using path + "\\"+file, use os.path.join(path, file).

Comment: I think it should be `if file.find("_ready") > -1:` if you want to generalize it to files where the substring can be at first position (index 0). Not sure whether it was intended or a bug, since in the original question, the substring seems to be never at  index 0

Answer (score 1):

```
from os import rename, listdir

fnames = listdir('.')
for fname in fnames:
    if fname.endswith('.txt'):
        new_name = fname.replace('_ready', '_busy')
        rename(fname, new_name)
```

this is what you probably you need. still i dint understood you?

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
old_string = "a_ready"
new_string = old_string.replace('_ready', '_busy')
```

Comment: Works pretty well so long as you don't have any `i_am_so_ready_for_this.txt` or similar.

Comment: It doesn't work with files. please see my code above. do you know what is the problem?

Comment: @Supertwisters `file` is a [python function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) use rename `file` to something else...

Answer (score 0):

string.replace() is what you seek

check it out [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html), it's right at the bottom

You can use

```
for file in files:
    output.append( file.replace(oldString, newString) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like(if the string is constant):

```
old_string = "a_ready"
new_string = old_string[:1]+"_busy"
```

Though I think @Selva has a better way of doing it.

Comment: How are yo using it?  see [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) on how to use `replace()`